# Is traffic exiting a VPN node encrypted?

Tags: vpn

If I am using a VPN connection, does the traffic exiting its node remain encrypted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In reference to the encryption a VPN provides, it is only valid in the tunnel it creates.  So once the traffic leaves the tunnel, it is no longer encrypted by the VPN.

Comment: Thanks. I thought so. Now if I wanted the connection between say the VPN exit point or node and the site I was browsing how can I achieve that without using a proxy?

Comment: Connect to the site using the https protocol - assuming it supports it.

Comment: @Linker3000 - What if the site doesn't support HTTPS?

Comment: The site will need to support some form of encryption otherwise at least some part of your connection will be unprotected. Going via a proxy will not help in this respect.

Comment: Your question is very vague.  Can you give more information as to what you are trying to do?  Who are you trying to prevent from seeing your data?  Are you VPNing into a work network and trying to make sure your connection to an internal website is secure?

Comment: @Keltari - What I am trying to achieve is when I am using a VPN connection any site I browse to remains secure and encrypted. For example (based on the assumption that cnn.com does not have a SSL certificate), I visit CNN.com I would like to make sure that any of my browsing remains anonymous.

Comment: I think I understand what you are asking.  A VPN does not offer anonymity, just a secure connection between two points.  You can not VPN to websites.  Also, HTTPS does not offer anonymity, it just offers a secure connection.  Neither of these technologies offer what you want.

Comment: @Keltari - Would it offer anonymity if used a service such as HideMyAss as I would imagine the IP address being logged would be HideMyAss'. Alternatively what technologies offer anonymity?

Comment: Regardless of what people say, its practically impossible to be anonymous on the internet.  Anonymizers help cover your trail, but depending on how hard someone looks they will be able to find you.  The best way to prevent someone from seeing your IP address is NOT to use your IP address.  Go to a internet cafe, or an open wifi.